Continuous function property and right control
Assume $X$ is a compact metric space and $C$ is closed in $X$, and $U$ is an compact neighborhood in $X$ containing $C$. Assume $f:U\times [0,1]\rightarrow X$ is continuous and $f(c,t)=c$ for all $c\in C$.
Then show
For every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $c\in C$ and $d(x,c)<\delta$ then $d(f(x,s),f(x,t))<\epsilon$ for all $s,t\in [0,1]$.
Attempt:
Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $f|_{C\times I}$ is uniformly continuous, there exists $\delta_1>0$ such that for every $(c,t),(c',t')\in C\times I$, if $d((c,t),(c',t'))<\delta$ then $d(c,c')<\epsilon$.
Choose $\delta_2>0$ such that for every $(x,t),(x',t')\in U\times I$, if $d(x,x')+|t-t'|<\delta_2$ then $d(f(x,t),f(x',t'))<\epsilon$.
But $\delta = \rm{min}(\delta_1,\delta_2)$ doesn't work.

For every $(x,t)\in C\times [0,1]$ pick a radius $\delta(x,t)>0$ such that $d(f(x,t),f(y,s))<\varepsilon$ for all $(y,s)\in U\times [0,1]$ with $d((x,t), (y,s))<2 \delta(x,t)$. Such a $\delta(x,t)$ exists by continuity. Now use that $C\times [0,1]$ is compact to get a finite subcover of $$C\times [0,1]\subseteq \bigcup_{(x,t)\in C\times [0,1]} B((x,t), \delta(x,t)).$$ Can you finish from here?
